# How to assign a scan list to a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I have developed an application that scans existing wifi signals surrounding my device and shows their names and their strength as well as follows :

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

List <ScanResult> results = wm.getScanResults ();

String otherwifi="The existing network is:\n\n";
System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());     
System.out.println(result.level);
for (ScanResult result: results) {  
  otherwifi+=result.SSID+":"+result.level+"\n";
  tv.setText (otherwifi);
}
```

and this is System.out.println :

```
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): rubelwifii
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): -50
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): aliwifi
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): -92
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): ABDULHAKEEM
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): -55
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): shamwifi
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): -70
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): Fuselage
>05-11 10:08:30.860: I/System.out(27621): -84
```

Now I want predefine each one of them as variable to use them for further processing ?

Comment: Are you asking how to store the results from the list in a variable?

Comment: i am asking how to give them a defined name in eclipse for example 
name1= rubelwifii 
strength1 =-50 
name2=ABDULHAKEEM
strength2= -55 
and so on 
hope you get my point and help me with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
// pre-defined names and strengths...
String name1 = "rubelwifii";
int strength1 = -50;
String name2 = "aliwifi";
int strength2 = -92;
String name3 = "ABDULHAKEEM";
int strength3 = -55;
String name4 = "shamwifi";
int strength4 = -70;
String name5 = "Fuselage";
int strength5 = -84;

// a hashmap to store your results
HashMap<String, ScanResult> hashMap = new HashMap<String, ScanResult>();

tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

List <ScanResult> results = wm.getScanResults ();

String otherwifi="The existing network is:\n\n";
System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());     
System.out.println(result.level);
for (ScanResult result: results) { 
    // store the result in a hashmap so you can get at it later
    hashMap.put(result.SSID.toString(), result);

    otherwifi+=result.SSID+":"+result.level+"\n";
    tv.setText (otherwifi);
}

// do something with the first and second result
ScanResult result1 = hashMap.get(name1);
ScanResult result2 = hashMap.get(name2);

// compare strength of #1 to the predefined value... (I'm assuming int is the data type)
if ( result1.level == strength1 ) {
    // do something
}

// do same for #2
if ( result2.level == strength2 ) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback 
but the strength value are not constant ... they are varying as the device is moving so i wanted to get strength results that obtained form the scan process and then use them 
hope yup get my point  
would you like to switch to chat for better explanation i would really appreciated because i really need help plz @Ryan j

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
// String key;
for (ScanResult result: results) {

   // key = cleanYourVarname(result.wifiName);
   // hm.put(key, result);

   /* key should be a clean string I assume wifi name as result.SSID */
   hm.put(result.SSID.toString(), result);

}
// retrieve  
hm.get("rubelwifii");
```

Comment: try this
hm.put(result.SSID.toString(), result);

Comment: bro i am trying to use another method but i still have problem maybe you can help me i jsust posted a question here explaining it 
can you check it form me and help me with it this is the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590743/if-statment-in-eclipse

or would you like to switch to chat ? 
i would really really appreciate you kind help