# if statement in Eclipse

Tags: java, if-statement

I am using if statement to get some specific information of the wifi signal  surrounded my device but when I tried to use that values which are d1,d2 and d3 out side the if statement it shows me an error?
any idea how to solve this

this is the codes I used:

```
for (ScanResult result: results) {  
    String NAME = result.SSID;
    if (NAME.equals("rubelwifii" )) {
        float s1=result.level;
        float  d1 =30*(1-(2*(s1+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(d1);
    }
    if  (NAME.equals("ABDULHAKEEM" ))  {
        float s2=result.level;
        float  d2 =30*(1-(2*(s2+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(d2);
    }
    if (result.SSID.equals("shamwifi" ))  {
        float s3=result.level;
        float  d3 =30*(1-(2*(s3+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s3);
        System.out.println(d3);
    }

float    distanc = d1+d1+d3;
System.out.println(distanc);
```

Comment: define the variables outside the if statements

Comment: ... otherwise, they are out of scope and you can't use them.

Comment: even if we defined them outside the if statement still get the error and it is suggested to define the as follow 
                float d1=0;
      float d2=0;
      float d3=0; 
and if i did so the total distance=0 ;
how we can solve it plz

Comment: total distance should be 0 in case none of your if-statements return true. Are you sure result.SSID match those strings?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin yeah i am sure because i can find them in the system out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvements:

You shouldn't compare NAME.equals("ABDULHAKEEM" ) because NAME might be null, which would throw an exception.

You don't need to do result.SSID.toString(). result.SSID is already a String.

Use else ifs to improve the speed (don't need to check another 2 times if the first time was a match).

```
        float s1=0;
        float d1=0;
        float s2=0;
        float d2=0;
        float s3=0;
        float d3=0;

        for (ScanResult result: results) {  
            String name = result.SSID;
            if ("rubelwifii".equals(name)) {
                s1=result.level;
                d1 =30*(1-(2*(s1+100)/100));
                System.out.println(result.SSID);
                System.out.println(s1);
                System.out.println(d1);
            }
            else if  ("ABDULHAKEEM".equals(name))  {
                s2=result.level;
                s2 =30*(1-(2*(s2+100)/100));
                System.out.println(result.SSID);
                System.out.println(s2);
                System.out.println(d2);
            }
            else if ("shamwifi".equals(name))  {
                s3=result.level;
                d3 =30*(1-(2*(s3+100)/100));
                System.out.println(result.SSID);
                System.out.println(s3);
                System.out.println(d3);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("name ["+name+"] was not one of the known spots");
            }
        }

        float distanc = d1+d1+d3;
        System.out.println(distanc);
```

Comment: still get the error and it is suggested to define the as follow float d1=0; float d2=0; float d3=0; and if i did so the total distance would equal to 0 ; how we can solve it plz

Comment: The two initializations are fine. Java inits floats as zero anyway. Don't fret about that kind of detail. Let me change my code and see if I understand what you *really* want to do

Comment: i am scanning for the existing wifi surrounded my device but i want only to get the strength of 3 routers out of the list thats why im trying to use if statement 
- @Alexandre Santos

Comment: Is the distance zero?

Comment: this is to show the output of result.level which is the signal strength 

sir would you like to switch to chat since stackoverflow is requiting to avoid extended discussion ... i would really appreciate your help

Comment: i am not able to join , i need to have at least 20  reputation :D 
so how can we do this sir ? 
Thanks for your cooperation ^_^

Comment: Please update your post with the results of the program: all System.outs

Comment: If s1 is 50 then the distance will be zero. Sorry. got to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your variables out side of your statements

```
float s1;
float d1;
float s2;
float d2;
float s3;
float d3;

for (ScanResult result: results) {  
    String NAME = result.SSID;
    if (NAME.equals("rubelwifii" )) {
        s1=result.level;
        d1 =30*(1-(2*(s1+100)/100));
    System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(d1);
    }
    if  (NAME.equals("ABDULHAKEEM" ))  {
        s2=result.level;
        s2 =30*(1-(2*(s2+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(d2);
    }
    if (result.SSID.equals("shamwifi" ))  {
        s3=result.level;
        d3 =30*(1-(2*(s3+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s3);
        System.out.println(d3);
    }

float distanc = d1+d1+d3;
System.out.println(distanc);
```

Comment: even if we defined them outside the if statement still get the error and it is suggested to define the as follow float d1=0; float d2=0; float d3=0; and if i did so the total distance=0 ; how we can solve it plz

Answer (score 0):

Scope in any c-like language is used for encapsulation. If you define variable in certain scope it is defined only in this scope (and its sub-scopes) but not outside. So, if you want to use variables at point where you calculate your `distanc` move definition of `d1` and `d2` to appropriate level with appropriate initialization (I guess `0.0f`):

Since your tabulation and parentheses of `for` loop are not clear I am not sure whether your calculation is into the loop or after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

if your if conditions don't return true, s1, s2, and s3 will not be created and you won't be able to use them later.. Your code should look like this:

```
for (ScanResult result: results) { 
float d1=0,d2=0,d3=0; 
    String NAME = result.SSID;
    if (NAME.equals("rubelwifii" )) {
        float s1=result.level;
        d1 =30*(1-(2*(s1+100)/100));
    System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(d1);
    }
    if  (NAME.equals("ABDULHAKEEM" ))  {
        float s2=result.level;
        d2 =30*(1-(2*(s2+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(d2);
    }
    if (result.SSID.equals("shamwifi" ))  {
        float s3=result.level;
        d3 =30*(1-(2*(s3+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s3);
        System.out.println(d3);
    }
    float    distanc = d1+d1+d3;
    System.out.println(distanc);
```

Note that I instantiate d1,d2 and d3 with 0, so if the if-statement isn't true, the distance wouldn't return nullPointerException

Comment: i tired your way but i get the distance = 0 , known that if statements are satisfied because i get the value of s1,s2,s3,d1,d2,and d3 at the system out 
any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare before loop    
float d1,d2,d3,s1,s2,s3;


for( ScanResult result: results ) {
 // your code here
    String NAME = result.SSID;
    if (NAME.equals("rubelwifii" )) {
        s1=result.level;
        d1 =30*(1-(2*(s1+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(d1);
    }
    if  (NAME.equals("ABDULHAKEEM" ))  {
        s2=result.level;
        d2 =30*(1-(2*(s2+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(d2);
    }
    if (result.SSID.equals("shamwifi" ))  {
        s3=result.level;
        d3 =30*(1-(2*(s3+100)/100));
        System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
        System.out.println(s3);
        System.out.println(d3);
    }
} // end for

// use this code out side the loop
float distanc = d1+d1+d3;
System.out.println(distanc);
```

Comment: even if we defined them outside the if statement still get the error and it is suggested to define the as follow float d1=0; float d2=0; float d3=0; and if i did so the total distance=0 ; how we can solve it plz

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace with your code

// declare before loop    
float d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3 = 0, s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 0;
String NAME;

for( ScanResult result: results ) {
// slightly changed
NAME = result.SSID.toString();
if (NAME.equals("rubelwifii" )) {
    s1=(float) result.level;
    d1 =30*(1-(2*(s1+100)/100));
    System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(d1);
}
else if (NAME.equals("ABDULHAKEEM" ))  {
    s2=(float) result.level;
    d2 =30*(1-(2*(s2+100)/100));
    System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
    System.out.println(s2);
    System.out.println(d2);
}
else if (NAME.equals("shamwifi" ))  {
    s3=result.level;
    d3 =30*(1-(2*(s3+100)/100));
    System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());
    System.out.println(s3);
    System.out.println(d3);
}
} // end for

// use this code out side the loop
float distanc = d1+d1+d3;
System.out.println(distanc);
```